# Projections in the tensor product of von Neumann algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, banach-algebras

This question seems elementary, but I have already asked an expert who does not know the answer, so I would like to post here.

Let $M$ and $N$ be von Neumann algebras, and let $M\bar{\otimes}N$ be their von Neumann algebra tensor product.

> **Question:** Can every projection in $M\bar{\otimes}N$ be expressed as
>   the supremum (join) of projections of the form $p\otimes q$, where $p$
>   and $q$ are projections in $M$ and $N$, respectively?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The answer is **no**.

*Proof.* Let $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{K}$ be any infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces, and let $\{\xi_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{\eta_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be sequences of any orthogonal vectors of norm $1$ in $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{K}$, respectively. Then $\zeta:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\xi_n\otimes\eta_n$ is an element of $\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{K}$ (the completion has been taken), but not an element of $\mathcal{H}\odot\mathcal{K}$ (the algebraic tensor product before taking completion). The rank-$1$ projection onto $\mathbb{C}\zeta$ is in $\mathbb{B}(\mathcal{H})\bar{\otimes}\mathbb{B}(\mathcal{K})$, but not in $\mathbb{B}(\mathcal{H})\otimes\mathbb{B}(\mathcal{K})$, and it cannnot be the supremum of projections of the form described in the question since it is of rank-$1$.

Comment: Nice. It would be interesting to see if the statement is true in the case of diffuse algebras.

Comment: @Adrián González-Pérez: Thank you for a good question. I will think about it.

Comment: @MasayoshiKaneda Hi Masayoshi, do you have an answer for diffuse algebras? I am also interested in this question

Comment: @user92646: Thank you for your interest and your question. I think the answer is no, regardless of diffuseness. Suppose that $\{p_\alpha\otimes q_\alpha\}$ is a set of projections in $M\otimes N$ such that $p_\alpha\in M$ and $q_\alpha\in N$. Let $p$ (resp., $q$) be the supremum of $\{p_\alpha\}$ (resp., $\{q_\alpha\}$) in $M$ (resp., in $N$). Then it is easy to see that $p\otimes q$, which is in $M\otimes N$, serves as the supremum of $\{p_\alpha\otimes q_\alpha\}$ in $M\bar{\otimes}N$.

Comment: Indeed, if $r$ is a projection in $M\bar{\otimes}N$ such that $p_\alpha\otimes q_\alpha\le r$ for all $\alpha$, then $p_\alpha\mathcal{H}\odot q_\alpha\mathcal{K}\subseteq(p_\alpha\otimes q_\alpha)(\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{K})\subseteq r(\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{K})$ for all $\alpha$. Thus $p\mathcal{H}\odot q\mathcal{K}\subseteq(p\otimes q)(\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{K})\subseteq r(\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{K})$, and hence $p\otimes q\le r$.

Comment: After all, any projection in $M\bar{\otimes}N\setminus M\otimes N$ cannot be the supremum of projections of the form $p\otimes q$ with $p\in M$ and $q\in N$. This gives an alternate and more complete answer to my original question.

Comment: @Adrián González Pérez: It was about your old question, but I answered in my comments above. Or, maybe you have already figured out. Thank you for asking, though.